# Clipping a graph drawn with DrawCurve()

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I've go a set of points that i use to draw a graph using DrawCurve, but i don't want the line to extend over the extents of a specified box?

Comment: Your case is not so clear (without code), so my best guess is draw the box after the curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Graphics object with which to draw the curve and set the Clip property to your box bounds.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip.aspx

Comment: Great thanks managed to get to this solution a couple of minutes before you answered. Will edit in my code.